# Ternary operator precedence in c

Tags: c, output, ternary-operator

In the following code output is 1 but it should be 2 . how ?

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
        int count=0,i;
        int num[4]={1,2,3,4};

        for(i=0;i<4;++i)
            count = count+(num[i]%2==1)?1:0;

        printf("%d",count);
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: http://pragmatictips.com/26

Comment: Naturally, `count += num[i] % 2;` was too complicated, and you decided that your program required branching instead.

Comment: I note that your original code and all of the answers given are wrong because `x%2==1` does not check for oddness in the first place. `x%2!=0` checks for oddness. *If the operand is negative then the remainder can be negative as well.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Operator precedence. Change the line to:

```
    count = count + ((num[i] % 2 == 1) ? 1 : 0);
```

Or, even better:

```
    count += num[i] % 2;
```

---

To explain: `+` has a higher precedence than `?:`. So your line as-is is actually being interpreted as:

```
    count = (count + (num[i] % 2 == 1)) ? 1 : 0;
```

So on each iteration of the loop, count is being set to either `1` or `0`, as follows:

```
  i   |  count  |  (num[i] % 2 == 1)  | count + (num...)  |  new count
------+---------+---------------------+-------------------+-------------
  0   |    0    |      1 (true)       |      1            |    1    
  1   |    1    |      0 (false)      |      1            |    1
  2   |    1    |      1 (true)       |      2            |    1             
  3   |    1    |      0 (false)      |      1            |    1
```

Comment: Precedence, not order.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
 count = count+(num[i]%2==1)?1:0;
```

to

```
count = count+((num[i]%2==1)?1:0);
```

`+` binary operator has higher precedence than conditional operator.

Comment: That's the smallest change that corrects the problem. Using `+=` would be an additional style improvement (and would eliminate the need for the extra parentheses).

Comment: @KeithThompson Yes, I'm only explaining the reason of the observed result and I let the proper solution as an exercise for the OP ;)